# Ansible - multiple items in path, but cannot use loop

Tags: ansible

I'm not sure how to describe the title or my question properly, feel free to edit.

I'll jump right in. I have this **working** piece of Ansible code:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ item.item.value.my_folder }}/{{ item.item.value.filename }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ my_stat.results }}"
  when: item.stat is defined and item.stat.exists and item.stat.islnk
```

If Ansible is run, the task is executed properly, and the file is removed from the system.

Now, the issue. What I want Ansible to do is loop over multiple items described in "path". This way I won't have to create a seperate task for each filename I want to be deleted.
Example:

```yaml
- file:
    path:
      - "{{ item.item.value.my_folder }}/{{ item.item.value.filename }}"
      - "{{ item.item.value.my_folder }}/{{ item.item.value.other_filename }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ my_stat.results }}"
  when: item.stat is defined and item.stat.exists and item.stat.islnk
```

But Ansible doesn't proces the items in the list described in 'path', so the filesnames will not be deleted.
I see I cannot use 'loop', since it is already in use for another value.

**Question**: How would I configure Ansible so that I can have multiple items in the path and let Ansible delete the filenames, and keeping the current loop intact.

-- EDIT --

Output of the tasks:

I've removed the pastebin url since I believe it has no added value for the question, and the answer has been given.

Comment: Where does the value of the attribute *other_filename* come from?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a sample of your actual data in `my_stat`.

Comment: You don't want to change your loop because you have a hard requirement about it or you don't want to change your loop because you need to `my_stat.results` and you don't see how to change your loop in order to achieve what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation, [`path`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-path) is of type `path`, so Ansible will only accept a valid path in there, not a list.

What you can do, though, is to slightly modify your loop and make a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) between your existing list and a list of the filenames properties you want to remove, then use those as the key to access `item.item.value` (or `item.0.item.value` now, since we have the `product` filter applied).

For example:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ item.0.item.value.my_folder }}/{{ item.0.item.value[item.1] }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ my_stat.results | product(['filename', 'other_filename']) }}"
  when: 
    - item.0.stat is defined
    - item.0.stat.exists 
    - item.0.stat.islnk
```

*PS: a list in a `when` is the same as adding `and` statements in the said `when`*

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm receiving a "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <itertools.product object at 0x1101d2880>". If desired, perhaps you can take a look at my original question and look at the pastebin URL to view the contents of the my_stat.
Also, I'm using Ansible 2.9

Comment: Those kind of `<iterator...>` or `<itertools...>` in Ansible version < 2.10 always means the same thing: add a `| list` filter to it, and you should be good to go. So: `loop: "{{ my_stat.results | product(['filename', 'other_filename']) | list }}"`

Comment: Or upgrade to a fresher version of Ansible and it will type cast the iterators to lists for you already.